# Блок при наведении HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Недавно начал учиться. Помогите, пожалуйста, второй день не могу сделать. 
При наведении должно получиться так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А у меня выходит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Html:

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <ul class="menu clearfix">
                    <li class="menu__item employer">
                        <a href="#">
                            Работодателям
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.menu {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
.menu__item {
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
margin-top: 9px;
margin-right: 13px;
display: block;
padding: 0px 13px 0px 13px;
}
.menu__item a {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 14px;
height: 100%;
width: 100%
}
.menu__item a:hover {
color: #d66dff;
background: #4a2554;
box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

И границу лучше сделать картинкой или кодом?

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: Замените в CSS `.menu__item a:hover {` на `.menu__item:hover {`.
P.S.: Согласен с предыдущим комментатором. Вопрос описывает частный случай и бесполезен для остальных участников сообщества, поэтому его следует удалить.

Comment: @Pyramidhead, заменил, все остается также, только пропадает картинка, потому что она фоном

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы картинка в бэкграунде не пропадала используй background-color при ховере, а не переписывай все свойство background

Comment: Спасибо! А с блоком как решить проблему, не знаете?

Comment: @ArturAllamuradov  объясните что   у вас не получается ?

Comment: @НикитаФаст, при наведении меняется фон только у текста, а мне нужен весь блок

Comment: @ArturAllamuradov а пробовали применять его не к тегу `а` а для самого `li` ?

Comment: @НикитаФаст да, ничего не меняется(

Comment: Задай li высоту 100%, а если хочешь все применять к а, то как минимум зазай ему display: inline-block. И перенеси в него паддинги и картинку

Comment: @НикитаФаст, Да, как связаться с вами?

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #ccc;
}

li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

li a {
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

li:hover {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7XHB.png);
  background-color: rgba(200, 10, 0, 0.5);
  background-size: cover;
  /*это для background-image*/
}

li:hover a {
  color: #fbfbfb;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item5</a></li>
</ul>
```